# How to handle token expiration in reactjs using firebase and passing idToken in axios interceptor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to integrate firebase login in my react project while passing the idtoken into the Axios interceptor for API consumptions.

But I have noticed that my idtoken gets expired and that same old token gets passed into my API.

How can I refresh the token and pass the fresh token into my Axios interceptor?

Following is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Navigation from "./Navigation";
import firebase from "./firebaseApp";
import axios from "axios";

import "./index.css";
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    authenticated: undefined,
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((authenticated) => {
      if (authenticated) {
        let idTokenfinal;
        firebase
          .auth()
          .currentUser.getIdToken()
          .then((idToken) => {
            idTokenfinal = idToken;

            this.setState({
              authenticated: true,
            });
          })
          .catch((e) => {
            alert(e);
          });
        firebase.auth().onIdTokenChanged(function (user) {
          if (user) {
            // User is signed in or token was refreshed.
            user.getIdToken().then((idToken) => {

              idTokenfinal = idToken;

            });
          }
        });
        axios.interceptors.request.use(
          (config) => {
            if (config.data && config.data.authToken) {
              config.data.authToken = idTokenfinal;
            }
            return Promise.resolve(config);
          },
          function (error) {
            // Do something with request error
            return Promise.reject(error);
          }
        );
      } else {
        this.setState({
          authenticated: false,
        });
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
   return this.state.authenticated !== undefined &&
      this.state.authenticated !== null ? (
      <Navigation authenticated={this.state.authenticated} />
    ) : (
      <div className="loader"></div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to `onAuthStateChanged`, there is [onIdTokenChanged](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onidtokenchanged) that gives you a new ID token whenever it's refresh.  That refresh happens automatically every hour.  If you have a listener here, there's no need to call `getIdToken` every time - just use the last value provided to the ID token listener.

If you don't want to use the listener for some reason, you can call `getIdToken(true)` to refresh the token each time, but that will add overhead to each call.  It's better to use the value provided by the listener.

Comment: As I said, it works similar to `onAuthStateChanged` as you're using it now.  The link I provided to the API documentation gives more details.  If you're having problems making it work, I suggest posting a new question with the code that isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: I have updated the code. But still the same issue.
can you tell if its done correctly ?Thanks

Comment: If you have a second question, please post it separately.

Comment: @DougStevenson hey there, I'm having a similar problem: could I please get your help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64289904/why-is-the-getidtoken-method-sending-expired-tokens